# What is the difference between using or avoid using CALCULATE to re-instate a filter?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having 2 codes as shown below. The goal is to remove the filter from the filter context. VALUES is used to re-instate the filter.

1. Approach 1:

   AVERAGEX(
   VALUES('Sales Order'[Sales Order]),
   [Revenue]
   )
2. Approach 2:

   CALCULATE(
   AVERAGEX(
   'Sales Order',
   [Revenue]
   ), VALUES('Sales Order'[Sales Order])
   )

What is the difference between these approaches?

Comment: 1st. neither one is removing any filter. 2nd. Is 'Sales Order'[Sales Order] a PK in 'Sales Order' table?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question: "what is the difference between using or avoiding CALCULATE?" is that CALCULATE (and CALCULATETABLE) is the only function to change a filter context. Other techniques do not change the filter context.

The two formulas in the post are not changing the filter context. But the first one computes the average [Revenue] per 'Sales Order'[Sales Order] in the current filter context

The second one computes the average of [Revenue] computed per each row of the 'Sales Order' table, that generally is different, unless 'Sales Order'[Sales Order] was the PK of the 'Sales Order' table.

Also, the approach n. 2 is usually wrong, since it would misbehave if duplicate rows exist in the 'Sales Order' table, since a context transition happens when evaluating [Revenue], therere the measure would use all the duplicated rows matching the filter instead of only the currently iterated one.

Comment: What is the purpose of VALUES in approach 1? Is it same as AVERAGE( [Revenue] )

Comment: Please can you elaborate on "unless 'Sales Order'[Sales Order] was the PK of the 'Sales Order' table." - how does PK affect this calculation.

Comment: if it is the Primary Key then each row has a different value for 'Sales Order'[Sales Order]. If not, then a 'Sales Order'[Sales Order] can be repeated over multiple rows.
VALUES() in approach 1 is used as a table function that returns the distinct values of 'Sales Order'[Sales Order]. This means that if 'Sales Order'[Sales Order] appears on more than one row, it is returned only once.

Comment: Why does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax#example-2 have to use CALCULATE instead of the approach used in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax#example-1 ? Both are clearing a filter. can you advise.

Comment: the code in the two examples performs the same calculation. In the one with CALCULATE the ALL funciton is used as a filter modifier that removes the filter over DateTime[CalendarYear]. In the other one ALL is used as a table function that ignores any existing filter. If a filter over another DateTime table column existed, the first one would apply it and give a different result, sinche only the filter over CalendarYear is removed. The second one would ignore that filter too and give the same result. I hope it helps :)